# How to write simple Ruby wrapper for SQL methods to make this specs pass?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have

```
describe SQL do
  it "generates select * when from given" do
    SQL.from('tname').generate.should == 'select * from tname;'
  end
end
```

I would like write implementation for `from` and `generate` methods for `SQL` class.

Comment: is the SQL class derived from ActiveRecord?(asking since you've tagged this as ROR)  or it your own ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a real naive implementation of the above (assuming it is not derived from ActiveRecord) would be something like this.

```
class SQL
  def self.from(tname)
    SQL.new(tname)
  end

  def initialize(tname=nil)
    @tname = tname
  end

  def generate
    "Select * from #{@tname};"
  end
end
```

That will make your spec pass, but probably isn't want you actually want to do.